# Wrong hostname in cPanel notification emails

Tags: ssh, cpanel, hostname, whm, dedicated-server

In our dedicated server even we run "/usr/local/cpanel/bin/set_hostname" from SSH as ROOT all notifications from the server has wrong hostname URL. The problem remains only in notification mails and sometimes HTTPS URLs (but this one is cause of local DNS records i guess).

We already did:

1. Changed hostname from WHM
2. Changed RDNS records
3. Fixed etc/hosts
4. Run /usr/local/cpanel/bin/set_hostname [hostname]
5. Fixed WHM api1
6. Reboot :)
7. Read StackOverflow

So can anyone offer a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing wrong hostname values in one of the files Apache uses to build it's main configuration file "/var/cpanel/conf/apache/main" have solved the issue.

This solution had come from [cPanel Customer Support](https://tickets.cpanel.net). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

in my case  I edit "/etc/hosts" and remove old host name attached to server ip.